# ¿Cómo puedo ajustar el shadowcasting de canvas?

Tags: javascript

El siguiente código me genera sombras con los obstáculos al mover el ratón sobre el lienzo. ¿Cómo puedo aplicar menos luz cuanto más alejado está? Es decir, que sea una especie de gradiente, la luz es más tenue si está más alejado del ratón

```js
function getIntersection(ray,segment){
    let r_px = ray.a.x;
    let r_py = ray.a.y;
    let r_dx = ray.b.x-ray.a.x;
    let r_dy = ray.b.y-ray.a.y;

    // SEGMENT in parametric: Point + Delta*T2
    let s_px = segment.a.x;
    let s_py = segment.a.y;
    let s_dx = segment.b.x-segment.a.x;
    let s_dy = segment.b.y-segment.a.y;

    // Are they parallel? If so, no intersect
    let r_mag = Math.sqrt(r_dx*r_dx+r_dy*r_dy);
    let s_mag = Math.sqrt(s_dx*s_dx+s_dy*s_dy);
    if(r_dx/r_mag==s_dx/s_mag && r_dy/r_mag==s_dy/s_mag){
        // Unit vectors are the same.
        return null;
    }
    let T2 = (r_dx*(s_py-r_py) + r_dy*(r_px-s_px))/(s_dx*r_dy - s_dy*r_dx);
    let T1 = (s_px+s_dx*T2-r_px)/r_dx;

    if(T1<0) return null;
    if(T2<0 || T2>1) return null;

    return {
        x: r_px+r_dx*T1,
        y: r_py+r_dy*T1,
        param: T1
    };

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// DRAWING
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function draw(){

    // Clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    // Draw segments
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#999";
    for(var i=0;i<segments.length;i++){
        var seg = segments[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(seg.a.x,seg.a.y);
        ctx.lineTo(seg.b.x,seg.b.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    // Get all unique points
    var points = (function(segments){
        var a = [];
        segments.forEach(function(seg){
            a.push(seg.a,seg.b);
        });
        return a;
    })(segments);
    var uniquePoints = (function(points){
        var set = {};
        return points.filter(function(p){
            var key = p.x+","+p.y;
            if(key in set){
                return false;
            }else{
                set[key]=true;
                return true;
            }
        });
    })(points);

    // Get all angles
    var uniqueAngles = [];
    for(var j=0;j<uniquePoints.length;j++){
        var uniquePoint = uniquePoints[j];
        var angle = Math.atan2(uniquePoint.y-Mouse.y,uniquePoint.x-Mouse.x);
        uniquePoint.angle = angle;
        uniqueAngles.push(angle-0.00001,angle,angle+0.00001);
    }

    // RAYS IN ALL DIRECTIONS
    var intersects = [];
    for(var j=0;j<uniqueAngles.length;j++){
        var angle = uniqueAngles[j];

        // Calculate dx & dy from angle
        var dx = Math.cos(angle);
        var dy = Math.sin(angle);

        // Ray from center of screen to mouse
        var ray = {
            a:{x:Mouse.x,y:Mouse.y},
            b:{x:Mouse.x+dx,y:Mouse.y+dy}
        };

        // Find CLOSEST intersection
        var closestIntersect = null;
        for(var i=0;i<segments.length;i++){
            var intersect = getIntersection(ray,segments[i]);
            if(!intersect) continue;
            if(!closestIntersect || intersect.param<closestIntersect.param){
                closestIntersect=intersect;
            }
        }

        // Intersect angle
        if(!closestIntersect) continue;
        closestIntersect.angle = angle;

        // Add to list of intersects
        intersects.push(closestIntersect);

    }

    // Sort intersects by angle
    intersects = intersects.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.angle-b.angle;
    });

    // DRAW AS A GIANT POLYGON
    ctx.fillStyle = "#333";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(intersects[0].x,intersects[0].y);
    for(var i=1;i<intersects.length;i++){
        var intersect = intersects[i];
        ctx.lineTo(intersect.x,intersect.y);
    }
    ctx.fill();

}

// LINE SEGMENTS
var segments = [

    // Border
    {a:{x:0,y:0}, b:{x:640,y:0}},
    {a:{x:640,y:0}, b:{x:640,y:560}},
    {a:{x:640,y:560}, b:{x:0,y:560}},
    {a:{x:0,y:560}, b:{x:0,y:0}},


    {a:{x:500,y:150}, b:{x:500, y:200}},
    {a:{x:500,y:200}, b:{x:550, y:200}},
    {a:{x:550,y:200}, b:{x:550, y:150}},
    {a:{x:550,y:150}, b:{x:500, y:150}},

    {a:{x:300,y:150}, b:{x:300, y:200}},
    {a:{x:300,y:200}, b:{x:350, y:200}},
    {a:{x:350,y:200}, b:{x:350, y:150}},
    {a:{x:350,y:150}, b:{x:300, y:150}},

    {a:{x:300,y:350}, b:{x:300, y:400}},
    {a:{x:300,y:400}, b:{x:350, y:400}},
    {a:{x:350,y:400}, b:{x:350, y:350}},
    {a:{x:350,y:350}, b:{x:300, y:350}},

];

// DRAW LOOP
window.requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
var updateCanvas = true;
function drawLoop(){
    requestAnimationFrame(drawLoop);
    if(updateCanvas){
        draw();
        updateCanvas = false;
    }
}
window.onload = function(){
    drawLoop();
};

// MOUSE    
var Mouse = {
    x: canvas.width/2,
    y: canvas.height/2
};
canvas.onmousemove = function(event){   
    Mouse.x = event.clientX;
    Mouse.y = event.clientY;
    updateCanvas = true;
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="560"></canvas>
```